# Prove $e^{(z^2)}\sin(z)=a, a\in\mathbb{C}$ has infinitely many solutions in a circular sector arbitrarily thin, except at most for one number

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm taking complex analysis right now. I have been asked for homework:

> Prove there exists $\alpha \in (-\pi,\pi]$ such that $\forall\epsilon\in(0,\pi)$, the equation:
> $$f(z)=e^{(z^2)}\sin(z)=a$$
> $\forall a\in\mathbb{C}$ with at most a single exception, has infinitely many solutions in the circular sector: $$\{re^{\theta}:  r>0, \alpha-\epsilon<\theta<\alpha+\epsilon\}$$

I have been searching, and I have found Great Picard's Theorem. I know that $f$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$. So $f$ satisfy Picard's Theorem in every punctured neighborhood of $\infty$. I have no clue on how to proceed and relate this to the circular sector.

I am also using Picard's Theorem, which I think is pretty advanced for my level. It is possible to do this problem in a more elementary way without using Picard?, If not, could you tell me why Picard is the only way?

Thanks in advance.